# Cannot get to redirect apache on port 80 to tomcat 8443

Tags: redirect

My virtual hosts in Apache 2.4 For the regular website on Apache 2.4 port 80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName trident.openways.us
  ServerAlias openways.us/Trident
  ProxyPass / https://openways.us:8443/Trident
  ProxyPassReverse / https://openways.us:8443/Trident
  Redirect Permanent /Trident https://openways.us:8443/Trident
</VirtualHost>
```

To redirect calls on port 80 to Tomcat SSL

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName  trident.openways.us  
    ServerAlias openways.us/Trident  
    ProxyRequests on  
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    <Proxy *>  
        Order deny,allow  
        Allow from all  
    </Proxy>  
     SSLProxyEngine on  
     ProxyPass /Trident  https://openways.us:8443/Trident  
     ProxyPassReverse /Trident  https://openways.us:8443/Trident  
  </VirtualHost>
```

My Tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"   
           connectionTimeout="20000"  
           redirectPort="8443" />  

<Connector port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"   
           SSLCertificateFile="C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\openways.us_ssl_certificate.cer"   
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\_.openways.us_private_key.key"   
           SSLPassword="changeit"   
           SSLCertificateChainFile="C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\-.openways.us_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer"   
           keyAlias="tomcat" SSLProtocol="TLSv1"/>  

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->  
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Despite different configurations tested, my investigation on the web, I can not get them to work, except when the redirection is done to

http://openways.us:8080/Trident, but then without SSL

Please help recommending me the correct configuration or place to investigate

Answer (score 1):

I finally investigated many sources in past two days, and reached to configurations that worked perfectly as follows:

First of all

in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>     
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/openways/"
    ServerName www.openways.us
    ServerAlias openways.us
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/openways/">
    </Directory>
     Redirect Permanent / https://www.openways.us    
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>  

    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.84\webapps"
    ServerName openways.us
    ServerAlias trident.openways.us
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /Trident http://openways.us:8080/Trident/

    <Location "/Trident">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>  


<VirtualHost *:8443>  

    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.84\webapps"
    ServerName openways.us
    ServerAlias trident.openways.us
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /Trident https://openways.us:8443/Trident/

    <Location "/Trident">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

In httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443  

<VirtualHost *:443>    

SSLEngine on  
SSLCertificateFile
"C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\openways.us_ssl_certificate.cer"  
SSLCertificateKeyFile"C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\_.openways.us_private_key.key"  
    ServerName openways.us  
    ServerAlias trident.openways.us  
    ProxyRequests Off  
    SSLProxyEngine on  
    SSLEngine On  
    SSLProxyVerify none  
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off  
    ProxyPass /Trident https://openways.us:8443/Trident/  

    <Location "/Trident">  
      Order allow,deny  
      Allow from all  
    </Location>  
SSLCACertificateFile  
 "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\-.openways.us_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer"  


</VirtualHost>
```

In Tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"   
           connectionTimeout="20000"  
           redirectPort="8443" />  

<Connector port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"   
           SSLCertificateFile="C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\openways.us_ssl_certificate.cer"   
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\_.openways.us_private_key.key"   
           SSLPassword="xxxxxxxx"   
           SSLCertificateChainFile="C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\-.openways.us_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer"   
           keyAlias="tomcat" SSLProtocol="TLSv1"/>  

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->  
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I sincerely hope this solution help others like me in their initial steps to configure SSL certificates and combinations of Apache / Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
ServerName www.openways.us/Trident
ServerAlias openways.us/Trident
```

This doesn't match any host as the host never contains any part of the path.

Remove them, first:

```
ServerName www.openways.us
ServerAlias openways.us
```

Then, supposedly the lower `<VirtualHost *:80>` is trying to be the SSL version, but it only uses SSL on its connection to the Tomcat server  behind. It doesn't implement SSL to the client at all, i.e.

```
client <--HTTP(80)--> proxy <--HTTPS(8443)--> tomcat
```

While both of these would do:

```
client <--HTTPS(443)--> proxy <--HTTPS(8443)--> tomcat

client <--HTTPS(443)--> proxy <--HTTP(8080)--> tomcat
```

For that, you'd need to have a [HTTPS virtual host](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts), instead.

Comment: I have tried changing the servers and Virtual host as follows

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName  trident.openways.us  
    ServerAlias openways.us/Trident  
    ProxyRequests on  
    ProxyPreserveHost On  
    <Proxy *>  
        Order deny,allow  
        Allow from all  
    </Proxy>  
  SSLProxyEngine on  
     ProxyPass /Trident  https://openways.us:8443/Trident  
     ProxyPassReverse /Trident  https://openways.us:8443/Trident  
  RedirectMatch ^/$ http://openways.us/Trident  
  </VirtualHost>

Comment: The SSL definitions are in the server.xml configuration, I do not get a correct path to Tomcat

Comment: Your Apache won't use certificates from Tomcat configuration.

Comment: Esa, thanks for your comment. Apache has its own definitions and SSL certificates. Tomcat is having separate certificates in the subdomain

Comment: I don't see any subdomains in your configuration and your Apache VirtualHost is clearly plain HTTP. I don't see any point having TLS (only) between the proxy and the Tomcat.

Comment: I reconfigured www.openways.us  to   trident.openways.us

Comment: The SSL configuration for  Apache is done in httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>  
ErrorLog "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\logs\error.log"  
TransferLog "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\logs\access.log"  
SSLEngine on  
SSLCertificateFile    "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\openways.us_ssl_certificate.cer"  
SSLCertificateKeyFile  
 "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\_.openways.us_private_key.key"  
SSLCACertificateFile  
 "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\-.openways.us_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer"  
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Not related, doesn't affect this VirtualHost on port 80 at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use mod_jk (Apache Tomcat Connectors) to do the same.
https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/